# Xamarin.iOS - Unable to archive for publishing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm having to rebuild 2 client Enterprise Apps and I've been able to build a release .ipa for one of them but for the other App I'm unable to *archive for publishing*.

The build error is:

**/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: Tool exited with code: 1. Output: error: unable to open executable 'bin/iPhone/Release/HGIPeople.app/HGIPeople': No such file or directory
(HGIPeople.iOS)**

Unfortunately we are having to use Xcode6.4 (due to compatibility issues with Good Dynamics Bindings and iOS9)

Xamarin details are;

> Version: 9.4.1.25 (Enterprise Edition)
>
> Branch: master
>
> Build date: 2016-01-29 16:59:11-0500

So to recap I can build for one app but not the other, the problematic App runs fine in the Simulator.  The folder / project structure seems the same for both Apps.

Hopefully someone out there has an idea.

Cheers

Steve

**SOLVED**

Thanks to everyone who posted.  Unfortunately for the build I'm forced to use Xcode 6.x due to compatibility with a third party security binding and iOS9.

Anyway after recreating the project and still having the same issue, I then checked all of the references and found the problem, Google Maps. The fix was:

> Removed the Nuget Google Maps package (this included Google.Maps.dll)
>
> Referenced an older (and much larger) version of Google Maps (GoogleMaps.dll, noticed the filename difference)
>
> Cleaned and deleted the obj/bin (which I think is always good practise to make sure you have a clean start)

I was then able to build and publish the App, phew!

Comment: Did you try cleaning and then archving ?

Comment: Does the app run fine on a physical device?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Diagnostic MSBuild Output to see if it helps provide some more info concerning the error so we might be able to provide more assistance.

In Xamarin Studio, under `Preferences` / `Build`, set the Log to Diagnostic (make sure you restart XS and **Clean All** on your solution/project)

[image]

> To enable diagnostic MSBuild output within Visual Studio:
>
> Click Tools > Options...
> In the left-hand tree view, select Projects and Solutions > Build and Run
> In the right-hand panel, set the MSBuild build output verbosity dropdown to Diagnostic
> Click OK
> Clean and rebuild your package.
> Diagnostic output is visible within the Output panel.
> To enable diagnostic MSBuild output within Xamarin Studio/OS X:
>
> Click Xamarin Studio > Preferences...
> In the left-hand tree view, select Projects > Build
> In the right-hand panel, set the Log verbosity drop-down to Diagnostic
> Click OK
> Restart Xamarin Studio
> Clean and rebuild your package.
> Diagnostic output is visible within the Errors Pad ( View > Pads > Errors ), by clicking the Build Output button.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

(Recap of email)

First and foremost Xamarin.iOS 9 was the point where we started to target Xcode 7. As such we'd not be able to officially provide support. There are, however, a few things you may wish to try.

1. As SushiHangover suggested, you may get more details information by forcing a verbose / diagnostic build output that may (or may not) assist in diagnosing the issue. You can [find more information here](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs-#verbose-build-output-logs).
2. Ensure you're uninstalling the app from your devices / simulators, cleaning the project, and manually deleting the /bin and /obj folders in your project.
3. Downgrade your Xamarin tools to the latest supported by Xamarin.iOS 8 (not recommended and also would not be supported)
4. Update your tools to the latest Stable releases.  This would be the recommended course in order for us to properly support.